# twitter bootstrap grids variable height based on image size proportional

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am attaching an image i just want to stack my blog posts like this.
am using twitter bootstrap 3.0. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2W1t.jpg

I already used Masonry and Salvattore JS solutions but not working in my case.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.
Ady

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem with Bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: Can you please share some code ? may be just a sample using jsfiddle

Comment: http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/12/working-with-variable-height-css-floats.html Am using this code but the only issue is distance from bottom is not equal. as you can see in this link.

Comment: http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p665/benknowscode/variable-height-floats-js-calcs_zpsaa54b1a6.png See the bottom distance is not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "but not working in my case". Bootrap grid is row oriented, so you can't really use it to make columns where items move from one column to another based on screen width.

But you can make 3 columns in Bootstrap grid:

Make a single row, with 3 4-cell columns, then in each column create as many rows as you want with 12-cell (full row).

eg:

```
<div class="row">  <!-- entire screen -->
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- left column -->
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 1.1 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 1.2 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 1.3 </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- center column -->
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 2.1 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 2.2 </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- right column -->
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 3.1 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 3.2 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 3.3 </div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> Item 3.4 </div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but see the design item height is different in each column.

Comment: no problem, just put items with different heights instead of the items I placed, it will be aligned correctly as in your screenshot.

Comment: did you try placing the items in the html I provided?   ie. replace "Item *" with your items,  it should work just fine with variable height items.

Comment: Thanks Iftah I will try it today, Thanks anyway